# Adding Dynamic Inputs , getting value from Dynamic dynamic generate input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I created a dynamic Form with JavaScript, with `AddChapitre` function and I want to get number value from an input text `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="grandTitreNbr1">`. And created "numbers value" inputs when I click to `addChapitre` button using `AddFeild()` function `<button id="b1" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addFields()">add titres</button>` .

The problem is when I click in `addChapitre` I get the The Chapitre Form hidden.
Here is it in JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/javagose/6veqe55v/1/

This image will show the problem:

[image]

```
function addChapitre() {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

    var addChapitre =
        '<div class="panel panel-success"> <div class="panel-heading"> <h2 class="panel-title">' +
        '<a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" href="#collapse" class="collapsed">chapitre : ' + j +
        ' </a></h2></div><div class="panel-body" id="Chapitre' + j + '">';

    newdiv.innerHTML += addChapitre;

    addChapitre1 =
        '<div class="panel-collapse" id="collapse' + j + '" >' +
        '<form class="form-horizontal"><div class="form-group">' +
        '<label for ="ChapTitre' + j + '">Titre du chapitre</label>' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="ChapTitre' + j +
        '" placeholder=" titre du chapitre ' + j + '"></div></form></div>';
    newdiv.innerHTML += addChapitre1;

    addChapitre2 =
        '<div class="panel panel-success" id="grandTitres' + j + '">' +
        '<div class="panel-heading"><h2 class="panel-title">' +
        '<a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTitre" ' +
        'href="#collapseTitre" class="collapsed"> Grands titres des chapitre: ' + j + '</a></h2></div>';
    newdiv.innerHTML += addChapitre2;

    addChapitre2 =
        '<div class="panel-body"><div class="panel-collapse" id="collapseTitre" >' +
        '<form class="form-horizontal"><div class="form-group" id ="grandTitres1">' +
        '<label for ="grandTitreNbr1"> GRAND TITRE</label>' +
        '<input type="text " class="form-control" id="grandTitreNbr' + j + '">' +
        '<button id="b1" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addFields()">add titres</button>' +
        '<div id="grandTitresDiv' + j + '">' +
        '</div></div> </form></div></div> </div></div></div>';
    newdiv.innerHTML += addChapitre2;

    document.getElementById('conteneur').appendChild(newdiv);
    j++;
}

function addFields() {
    var number = document.getElementById("grandTitreNbr" + j + "").value;
    var container = document.getElementById("grandTitresDiv" + j + "");

    for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        // Append a node with a random text
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        var grandTitreTxt =
            '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="grandTitreTxt' + j +
            '" name="grandTitreTxt' + j + '"></div>';
        newdiv.innerHTML += grandTitreTxt;

        var grandTitreUpload =
            '<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox"> Pdf </label></div>' +
            ' <input type="file" name="fichier" id="fichier"' + j + ' accept="pdf" />';
        newdiv.innerHTML += grandTitreUpload;


        var grandTitreUpload =
            '<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox">video </label>' +
            '</div> <input type="file" name="fichier" id="fichier"' + j +
            ' accept="video" />';
        newdiv.innerHTML += grandTitreUpload;

        container.appendChild(newdiv);
        // Append a line break
        container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
}
```

Comment: since your post does not have the essential `html` and `js` codes, can you create a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and update your post with it's link please?

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/javagose/6veqe55v/1/

Comment: Wow... really? Why would you assume that everyone is able to understand French (or whatever this is)?

Comment: the code is working perfectly for me. since you are nor using jquery in your javascript you do not need it. therefor in jsfiddle in the left menu you can select "No-Library (pure JS)" and under it select "No wrap - in <head>". with these settings, your code will work just fine

Comment: Guys The problem is not solved when i click to add GrandTitres Button the   AddFeilds() Function Are Not called.